# Programming Pattern or coding style with multiple ifs/switches

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, coding-style

I have a table with some ids, and i want in default.aspx to open a certain page.aspx with a form, depending on the id.

What i have now is:

```
if(id_table ==1) {
response.redirect("PageBla.aspx");
}

if(id_table==2) {
response.redirect("Page21231.aspx");
}

if(id_table==6) {
....
}
 etc etc....
```

this is simple if i have small number of ids to check. But i will have dozens of ids to check. Is there any programming pattern or any other method of doing this without dozens of ifs or switchs/cases?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: "=" was substituted with "==".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be quite easy to have a lookup containing the ID's and urls. It could be in a database for flexibility, but you could also just throw them in a dictionary now, and add the database part later, if you find you need it.

You could declare the lookup as a field:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> redirectLookup = new Dictionary<int,string> {
    {1, "PageBla.aspx"},
    {2, "Page21231.aspx"},
    // .....
    {6, "somepage6.apx"}

};
```

And in your redirect logic:

```
string redirect;
if (redirectLookup.TryGetValue(id_table, out redirect)) 
    Response.Redirect(redirect);
else
    // some default action when that ID was not mapped.
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted ? Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Answer (score 5):

Just create a simple array of the URLs like this:

```
string[] urls = {"PageBla.aspx", "Page21231.aspx"};
response.redirect(urls[id_table]);
```

If you have a more complex use case, another option is to use [Convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration).
You can do it like that:

1. Your tables will have string IDs.
2. Your redirect code will be as simple as:

   ```
   Response.Redirect(tableId + ".asxp");
   ```

Comment: What happens with your code when id_table == 3? Array indexing is sequential, the id_table variable is not.  The use of dictionary, as demonstrated in other responses, is the correct solution.

Comment: Why do you assume that it is not sequential? The code shown is just a sample code? In case it is, the Dictionary is an overkill.

Comment: The code shown is obviously sample code very incorrectly representing the desired outcome. The fact that he didn't put ... between element 2 and 6 does not mean he didn't meant to. Just as the fact he used '=' in the 'if' statement does not mean he didn't mean '=='.

Comment: The assumption is to think that the values of the table_id will be in neat, natural number order EVEN when the OP has clearly indicated otherwise. What you have proposed is a potentially erroneous solution when better and safer solutions have already been posted. That’s the reason for my -1.

Comment: Please refer to YAGNI and Over-Engineering in Wikipedia.

Comment: I've edited my sample code. It had an error, i meant "id_table ==" not "id_table ="

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Dictionary<K,V>`, instead, like, mor or less, a *pseudocode*:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int, string> { {1, "PageBla.aspx"}, {2, "Page21231.aspx"}..}
```

and after in code:

```
 response.redirect(dic[id_table]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use The [Factory Design Pattern](http://miroprocessordev.blogspot.com/2011/11/design-patterns-series-4-factory.html) that doesn't reduce ifs statements but it encapsulate it.

**Update**

You can combine the other answers with this pattern to get well written code

Answer (score 1):

Keep links in a Dctionary:

```
    Dictionary<int, string> links = 
        new Dictionary<int, string>()
    {
        { 1, "One.aspx" },
        { 2, "Two.aspx" },
        { 3, "Three.aspx" }
    };
```

and use the like:

```
    Response.Redirect(links[id_table]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to store the page in the table, select the page to redirect to.